# Azure Storage breaks when I call AZSCloudBlob in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, azure-storage

I've followed this article: [Azure Storage Client Library for iOS](https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-ios) and their sample works. But now I am trying to bring the azure-related code to my own project. I added the framework per instructions and show up like this in my prosect:

[image]

But when I uncomment the 3rd line and try to build:

```
var containerURL: String = ""
let usingSAS = true
var blobs = [AZSCloudBlob]() // uncommenting this results into build error
//var container : AZSCloudBlobContainer = AZSCloudBlobContainer()
//var continuationToken : AZSContinuationToken?
```

I get this build error:
[image]

I've modeled my setting like this:
[image]

Any insight on how to fix this!?
I'm running Xcode 7.2 and iOS 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to make sure that you are pointing to usr/lib/libxml2.2.tbd
I think it inherently calls other sibling libs where if it was in another folder it can't.